# Error when trying to decore PDO Object

Tags: php, pdo

Hello I am trying to make a retrive password script, my password inside the database is coded and here is the script for retriving it:

```
<?php 
$salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";
include_once("config.php"); //include the settings/configuration
$password = null;

/* function svarzcane kam bazata */

$email = $_POST['email'];



try {

          $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); //our new PDO Object
          $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
       }  catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage(); //catch and show the error
       }  

          $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :getmail LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->bindParam(":getmail", $_POST['email']);    
          $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );

          $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      
          $stmt->execute(); 

while( $row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
$pass = $row['password']; 
}
```

The problem here is that it gives me an error in the line when I am trying to decode the password: **`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/cedecapr/public_html/retrive.php on line 18`**

How I can fix that ? any help will be apreciated. Thanks.

The decoding variable is defined inside a class file : `public $salt = "decoding code";`

as suggested by Barmer I can't use this utside the class code. than how to Bind the Value with the hash alghoritm.

how to change this line

```
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

to decode the result from the database. The Hash alghoritm is updated on the top of the code as wel..

Comment: is $password defined ?

Comment: inside the class file: public $password = null;

Comment: just to be sure is that piece of code inside a function ?

Comment: this is the php file which is executed once a form with the e-mail is submited, what other code it includes is inside include_once( 'class/user.php' );

Comment: Is this code inside a non-static class member function? The error is complaining that `$this` isn't valid, which means you're not in a method applied to an object.

Comment: Why are you calling `bindParam` with a parameter that doesn't exist in the query? `password` is a result, not a parameter.

Comment: you can either make a function with that code and put it inside a class or you can refer to the $password and $salt variable as a object property use `$class = new yourClass()`and refer to $password as `$class->password`

Comment: It seems like you have a basic misunderstanding about PHP variables, this has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: @Barmar is right this has to do with $password and $salt

Comment: the class which defins all thoose elements is inside the config.php here is the code of the class in short version: class Users {

public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
//store the parameters
$this->__construct( $params );
}

Comment: Don't try to post long code in comments, update your question. But it seems like you still don't understand that you can't use `$this` outside the class code.

Comment: Barmer I did updated the code, got the problem that I can't use this outside the code, than how to decode the result in this case ? I am getting the value from the database but it is coded. I did update on the question code icluding all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this line completely:

```
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

Your SQL statement doesn't contain a parameter named `:password`, so there's no need to bind any value to it. I would guess you did copy & paste of this line of code from some class method, where `$this` was meaningful.

I also wonder if it will make any difference if you do retrieve the password, since it appears that the database stores a SHA256 hash of the salted password.  Hashing is not reversible, so even if you do retrieve the content of the `password` column from your database, the user can't use this to log in.

I think you need to learn more about PHP coding, and also security, before you make any changes on the authentication system for any website.

Comment: I wonder why you answer such a question. If OP would really like to teach himself he could use the internet. But if he isn't able to do that I would not answer him.

Comment: @hek2mgl, for the sake of mentoring. Hopefully, the OP will realize that he can't copy & paste code without minimal understanding of it. And he definitely *shouldn't* write code in the security aspect of any app without understanding it.  He is [unconsciously incompetent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence).

Comment: what I didn't knew was that SHA256 hash was not reversible.

Comment: John, FYI, all hashing functions are not reversible. Because given a hash, even if you know it's the hash of "password," you don't know if it's *also* the hash of a string formed by entire content of "War and Peace." Because a hash function always maps a string of arbitrary length to a fixed length string of bits, and there can be strings of infinite length, there is no way a given hash *isn't* the result of multiple input strings. Therefore it's ambiguous which input string it came from.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

Should be:

```
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $password . $salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

You cannot use `$this->` outside of a class definition. Period. `\n`. `EOF`.